# Counting Rows with Constraint in Hierarchical Data

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, gaps-and-islands

I have hierarchical data that links instances of an entity using `DATE_FROM` and `DATE_TO`.

Please see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c19c/1).

Using `CONNECT_BY` I can determine the number of contiguous instances for each entity, i.e., the length of the "islands", which is mostly what I want. E.g., this gives expected lengths of islands for each entity with a `DATE_FROM` in 2014:

```
-- QUERY 1
SELECT 
  T.ENTITY_ID,
  MAX(LEVEL) MAX_LEVEL
FROM TEST T
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T.DATE_FROM) = 2014
CONNECT BY 
  T.ENTITY_ID = PRIOR T.ENTITY_ID
  AND T.DATE_FROM = PRIOR T.DATE_TO
GROUP BY T.ENTITY_ID
```

However, what I would like to do is count the rows in the islands where the `DATE_FROM` and `DATE_TO` span some minimum number of days. I don't want to break the island hierarchy when I do this.

So I tried this, but it's wrong. Results are not consistently what I am looking for.

```
-- QUERY 2
SELECT 
  T.ENTITY_ID,
  MAX(LEVEL) MAX_LEVEL,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN PRIOR T.DATE_TO - PRIOR T.DATE_FROM > 183 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END
  ) LONG_TERM_COUNT
FROM TEST T
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T.DATE_FROM) = 2014
CONNECT BY 
  T.ENTITY_ID = PRIOR T.ENTITY_ID
  AND T.DATE_FROM = PRIOR T.DATE_TO
GROUP BY T.ENTITY_ID
```

Which gives

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
| ENTITY_ID | MAX_LEVEL | LONG_TERM_COUNT |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
|         1 |         4 |               3 |
|         2 |         5 |               4 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

but I am looking for

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
| ENTITY_ID | MAX_LEVEL | LONG_TERM_COUNT |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
|         1 |         4 |               4 |
|         2 |         5 |               4 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

I need an Oracle solution. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm adding a bounty for this. If any requirements are unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WHERE-condition is evaluated after CONNECT BY, so your query does not start with the rows from 2014. It creates the hierarchy for each and every row in your table, you can easily see that when you remove the WHERE and the aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  T.ENTITY_ID,
  LEVEL,
  T.DATE_TO,  
  T.DATE_FROM,
  prior T.DATE_TO,
  prior T.DATE_FROM
FROM TEST T
CONNECT BY 
  T.ENTITY_ID = PRIOR T.ENTITY_ID
  AND T.DATE_TO = PRIOR T.DATE_FROM
order by 1,2
```

You need to use START WITH instead of a WHERE-condition:

```
SELECT 
  T.ENTITY_ID,
  LEVEL,
  T.DATE_TO,  
  T.DATE_FROM,
  prior T.DATE_TO,
  prior T.DATE_FROM
FROM TEST T
START WITH EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T.DATE_FROM) = 2014
CONNECT BY 
   T.ENTITY_ID = PRIOR T.ENTITY_ID
   AND T.DATE_TO = PRIOR T.DATE_FROM
```

So finally it's:

```
SELECT 
  T.ENTITY_ID,
  MAX(LEVEL) MAX_LEVEL, -- or COUNT(*)
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN  T.DATE_TO -  T.DATE_FROM > 183 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END
  ) LONG_TERM_COUNT
FROM TEST T
CONNECT BY 
  T.ENTITY_ID = PRIOR T.ENTITY_ID
  AND T.DATE_TO = PRIOR T.DATE_FROM
START WITH EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T.DATE_FROM) = 2014
GROUP BY T.ENTITY_ID
```

And you might get a wrong result if two rows in 2014 exist, so you need to start with the latest row in 2014:

```
SELECT 
  T.ENTITY_ID,
  MAX(LEVEL) MAX_LEVEL,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN  T.DATE_TO -  T.DATE_FROM > 183 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END
  ) LONG_TERM_COUNT
FROM TEST T
CONNECT BY 
  T.ENTITY_ID = PRIOR T.ENTITY_ID
  AND T.DATE_TO = PRIOR T.DATE_FROM
START WITH T.DATE_FROM = 
  (
    SELECT MAX(T2.DATE_FROM) 
    FROM TEST T2 
    WHERE T.ENTITY_ID = T2.ENTITY_ID
      AND T2.DATE_FROM >= DATE '2014-01-01'
      AND T2.DATE_FROM <= DATE '2014-12-31'
  )
GROUP BY T.ENTITY_ID
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd792/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement is correct. But one scenario that needs to be considered when `CASE WHEN T.DATE_TO - PRIOR T.DATE_FROM > 183` statement becomes `null` which will not be counted.

```
INSERT INTO TEST 
 VALUES (1,TO_DATE('20130101','YYYYMMDD'),TO_DATE('20140101','YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO TEST 
 VALUES (1,TO_DATE('20140101','YYYYMMDD'),TO_DATE('20150101','YYYYMMDD'));
```

From your data example the Case equivalent:

```
CASE WHEN 
      TO_DATE('20140101','YYYYMMDD') - PRIOR TO_DATE('20140101','YYYYMMDD') > 183
```

This gives `null` value;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with Oracle but a good approach could be to use the `RANK` Aggregate. 
For example:

```
SELECT 
 T.ENTITY_ID,
 T.DATE_FROM,
 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ENTITY_ID
 ORDER BY T.DATE_TO DESC) "Rank"
FROM TEST T
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T.DATE_FROM) <= 2014
```

Joining the `T.ENTITY_ID = Prior T.ENTITY_ID` AND `Rank = (PRIOR.Rank + 1)` could lead to the solution. As I said, it's only a suggestion how to approach.

I tried a little bit more and this is my solution with a SubQuery [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c19c/96/0)

```
SELECT 
 T.ENTITY_ID,
 MAX(LEVEL) MAX_LEVEL,
 (Select MAX("Rank") FROM
  (
    SELECT T2.ENTITY_ID AS ID, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.ENTITY_ID
    ORDER BY T2.DATE_TO DESC) "Rank"
    FROM TEST T2
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T2.DATE_FROM) < 2014 
  ) SubQ
  WHERE ID = T.ENTITY_ID
 ) "LONG_TERM_COUNT"
FROM TEST T
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T.DATE_FROM) = 2014
CONNECT BY 
  T.ENTITY_ID = PRIOR T.ENTITY_ID
  AND T.DATE_FROM = PRIOR T.DATE_TO
GROUP BY T.ENTITY_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think this really works. See my amended [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20e4a/1) where I added one row to entity 1. The result is now incorrect.